# Zapier - Using Code Action to process multiple actions

Tags: javascript, action, formatter, zapier

I'm new to both Javascript and Zapier, so please bear with me.

**CONTEXT**

I have a form that sends multiple choice results as single line items. This gets expensive to convert in Zapier using their "Formatter" action (a single multiple choice question with 10 answers will use up 10 actions!)

**PROBLEM**

I tried using Zapier's Code Action, which they say can use Javascript to process multiple actions in 1 Action. I believe I am piping in the information the correct way: [Code Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfoYW.png)

... but I have no idea how to write the code snippet to process these 2 fields.

**HELP**

I need a solution that can:

1. Process each field (Fruit, Movies) and remove empty entries (e.g. if the person taking the form selected "Apple" and "Coconut" for their favorite fruits, the fruit object should remove empty entry for "Banana" and return:

`Apple
Coconut`

2. Process multiple objects. In my example I need to process a "Fruit" object and a "Movies" object as I need to be able to refer to them separately when I put the information into Asana.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide!